# Change system.byte() value on datagridview cell click

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a form with a `DatagridViewImage` Column. This column gets loaded with 2 images of type system.byte().

How can I change the image value on DataGridview `cell_click` from image 1 to image 2 and vice versa?

Answer (score 3):

This may work for you:

1. I loaded 2 images
2. I created a DataGridViewImageColumn and set the name and headertext to images
3. I added the DataGridViewImageColumn to the DataGridView
4. I subscribed to the cell click event of the DataGridView
5. In the cell click event I checked to see if the cell that was clicked was in the image column
6. If the cell was in the image column I switched out the image.

Here is the code:

```
private Image image1 = Bitmap.FromFile("C:/Image1.png");
private Image image2 = Bitmap.FromFile("C:/Image2.png");

public void dgvInit()
{
    DataGridViewImageColumn imgColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    imgColumn.Name = "images";
    imgColumn.HeaderText = "images";
    imgColumn.Image = this.image1;          
    this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(imgColumn);
    this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
    this.dataGridView1.CellClick += new 
        DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellClick);          
}

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText == "images")
    {
        DataGridViewImageColumn imgColumn =
            (DataGridViewImageColumn)this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
        if (imgColumn.Image == this.image1) imgColumn.Image = image2;
        else imgColumn.Image = image1;
    }
}
```